# Shiny Autoreload Won't Recognize Changes Made in App.R

Tags: r, shiny

In my Shiny `app.R` file (which contains both `server` and `ui`), using `options(shiny.autoreload = TRUE)` doesn't do anything. After the server is started, it won't respond to new changes I make inside the `app.R` file. However, `options(shiny.port = 8008)` was able to change the port, so I think the options were being recognized but other conflicts prevented the Shiny app from reloading. The Shiny app is started using the `shinyApp` function. Any suggestions on how to get autoreload to work?

---

Update: the `options()` function is called right before I start the app using `shinyApp()`. The options values are being modified as indicated with the print calls.

```
options(shiny.autoreload = TRUE, shiny.port = 8008)
print(getOption("shiny.autoreload")) # prints TRUE
print(getOption("shiny.port"))       # prints 8008
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Also, I'm starting the shiny app with Rscript app.R, not from Rstudio. Will try in Rstudio in a bit, but I don't think this should matter (like other web dev frameworks).

Comment: Can you provide some more details - I just tried with the default "Old Faithful Geyser" app and it works as expected. Make sure you put `options(shiny.autoreload = TRUE)` outside the `ui` and `server` functions and save the file to reload.

Comment: @ValeriVoev Just updated the question. Yes, my `options()` call is outside of `ui` and `server`.